# Redirect non ssl to ssl on a specfic port , example 4080

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, centos

I am using this code in httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:4080>

# This will enable the Rewrite capabilities
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.key
ServerAdmin serveradmin
DocumentRoot "/etc/zpanel/panel/"
ServerName panel.mydomain.com
ServerAlias *.panel.mydomain.com
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
<Directory "/etc/zpanel/panel/">
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I need http://domain.com:4080 to redirect to secure ://domain.com:4080, which is happening but certificate is not working

If I remove the auto redirection code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) [https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}][1]
```

and goto secure: //domain.com:4080 in browser myself certificate shows up.

I need something like cpanels auto redirection to https

Try http://ziing.net:2087/

Comment: What is `auto redirection code` and what exactly is your question?

Comment: Cpanel certificate comes as default self signed . not with payed certificate.